# Is replacing images on Flickr (via Lightroom) possible in 2021? If so how long does it take?

Tags: lightroom, flickr, publishing

I published an image to Flickr using Lightroom. Afterwards I changed the development settings and, as LR diligently asked me to re-publish that image (explicitly asking if I wanted to replace it), I did. The process completed, I waited a few minutes to give Flickr some breathing room and went to see if the image had been replaced.
**[!]** *The above essentially translates to the workflow described in [Adobe's dated help page](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom-classic/help/prepare-send-or-post-photos.html#upload_to_flickr).*

Sadly, even after almost an hour, clearing my browser's cache and even trying the famous "jf Flickr" plugin, I had no luck in replacing the image.

To be clear, my intent is to *replace the actual image*, not change the metadata. Is this supported by any of the available Flickr plugins for Lightroom?
*As osullic kindly pointed out, the [Flickr API seems to support image replacement](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/replace.api.html).*

**Update** addressing osullic's answer.

Comment: Is there a problem with just deleting the image from Flickr and uploading a new image? I can be a bit "old school" in how I approach these things. I think Lightroom should do one job, and if you want to publish an image to Flickr, I'd just manage that task independently.

Comment: Flickr does still support replacing images [through their website](https://help.flickr.com/replace-a-photo-in-flickr-rks02ms1m), and also [via API](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/replace.api.html) (which is how Lightroom will interface with Flickr).

Comment: @osullic The alternatives your mention are obviously valid fallback options, but since Lightroom provides a publishing feature, I don't see why I shouldn't expect it to do what it's supposed to do, especially since Flickr apparently supports replacing images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

It works and is virtually immediate. Tested with the ["jf Flickr" Lightroom plugin](http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/flickr), the official one should work too. The "Mark to republish" feature doesn't republish images without actual changes. Ironically the only time I would use this feature is to force a republication of an unchanged image (as in this case).

---

**Details**

I did this in a hurry and changed the settings of one image but also changed the publishing service to use a watermark. In the end I got stuck wondering why the
images weren't watermarked after republishing them.

After several tests I found out, to my surprise, that "Mark to republish" only processes images with actual changes. Which makes me wonder what the point of this feature is, as changing an image already causes it to be marked for (re-)publishing.

This means that changing the watermark settings of a publishing service, marking all images for republishing and publishing them won't actually change the watermark on them.

Again, this was tested with the unofficial plugin mentioned above.
I suspect this to be the case with the official Flickr plugin too, as I changed to the "jf Flickr" plugin hoping to solve this issue in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

No idea about this process really, but I just googled it. [Adobe's online help](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom-classic/help/prepare-send-or-post-photos.html) says...

> Upload to Flickr
>
> Photos waiting to be published appear in one of two queues: New Photos
> To Publish or Modified Photos To Republish. Lightroom Classic uploads
> everything in both queues when you publish a photoset.
>
> 1. To publish photos to Flickr, do one of the following:
>
> - Select a photoset and click Publish.
> - Right-click (Windows) or Control-click (Mac OS) a photoset and choose Publish Now.
>
> 2. If prompted, click Replace to update published photos with newer versions.
>
> Note:
>
> If you experience problems uploading to Flickr using the Publish
> Services panel, make sure you are using the latest update: In
> Lightroom Classic, choose Help > Check For Updates.

So, do you need to "publish a photoset" or something?

Comment: The page you mention, while dated, exactly describes what I did.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested and the procedure is something like:

- authorize. If you have done this before unauthorize and authorize again
- if above step fail try to change your default browser to Edge
- drag the image in photostream, then press Publish button (upper right part of the screen)
- make changes on the image
- go to Photostream, select image and press again publish. If asked press update

Comment: Bing is not a browser, it is a search engine. In 2021, nobody should need to choose any specific browser. Use any modern browser.

Comment: @osullic, my mistake, I mean Edge. I had FIrefox as default and did not succeed to authorize. Change to Edge and authorize. Then return back :)